# count inodes recursively for multiple directories

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

i usually use the syntax below to find inodes for all directories in the "current" directory:

```
find . -printf "%h\n" | cut -d/ -f-2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

But now i would like to count several directories at once like for /home1 /home2 /home3 and so on, so i tried:

```
find /home*/* -printf "%h\n" | cut -d/ -f-2 | sort | uniq -c
```

it didn't give me the usual result as it would only count total inodes of each /home directory instead of the inode count of /home*/* contents.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It's disputable if you can really count inodes this way (think about hardlinks, should each one increase the count?) but I assume you are OK with the first command.

Analyze what `cut -d/ -f-2` does. In the first case it cuts here:

```
./example/foo/bar/…
         ^ here
```

In the second case it cuts here:

```
/home-whatever/whoever/baz/…
              ^ here
```

It seems it's not where you want to cut. Adjust the `cut` command.